# Add column to data frame that can identify changed rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where I changed the value of a column if there were duplicate rows. i.e. if columns A, B, C, D were the same for 2 rows, then the value of column E of the duplicate row was set to 0.

Now I want to see the rows where the value of E was changed by my code by adding a column that says “True”, if E value was changed, and “False”, if it was not changed. How do I add this column to my data frame?

This is my code:

```
cond1 = df.duplicated(subset=cols)          cond2 = df.loc[‘E’ == 0]
df[remarks] = np.where(cond1 & cond2, True, False)
```

I am getting a

```
cond2 = df[‘E’==0]
in get_loc
raise KeyError(key)from err
KeyError:False
```

Please help!

Comment: If it is the same question as your other post, then `df['remarks'] = m1|m2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.loc['E' == 0]` doesn't make sense, it's equivalent to `df.loc[False]` (since `'E' == 0` is first evaluated to `False`) and you don't have a `False` column, thus the KeyError.

What you want is:

```
cond2 = df['E'] == 0
```

Also, `df['remarks'] = np.where(cond1 & cond2, True, False)` is not needed, just assign the boolean Series directly:

```
df[remarks] = cond1 & cond2
```

Comment: @Smith can you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: sorry that was an accidental comment i didn’t even realize i posted it!

Comment: @Smith Is your issue solved? If not it would be preferable to comment to your answer or to edit your question so that everyone can get updates.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I'd say you're missing brackets for remarks, but the error lies in the syntax of the second condition. It has to be written like:

```
cond2 = df['E'] == 0
```

because the condition needs to be the column of the dataframe (df['E']) equal to some value.

Comment: `df.loc[df['E'] == 0]` would return a DataFrame and OP most likely expects a boolean series (else `cond1 & cond2` would fail)

Comment: yeah, you're clearly right, I was so focused on the syntax error of the command that I did not see the bigger error.

Comment: so i have cond2 = df['E'] == 0 and df[‘remarks’] = cond2, i don’t need cond1 anymore. but i am getting a setting with copy warning for df[‘remarks’] = cond2. is this because i have cond2 = df[‘E’] == 0?

Comment: I did not get any error with my test code (but I'm not sure the structure is the same as yours) can you paste the actual warning?

Comment: Warning (from warnings module) :
File "C: /Users/ smithab-1/Documents/duplicates_flag.py”, Line 24
df1 ['REMARKS'] = m1
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row indexer, col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stabl
e/user
_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: And m1 is the condition? Can you try  to use df1 ['REMARKS'] = df1['E'] == 0 instead to check if the issue is in the condition? Because I don't have the issue unfortunately

Comment: yes, m1 is the condition: df1[‘E’] ==0. I’m getting the same error even with your code: df1[‘REMARKS’] = df1[‘E’] == 0. Warning (from warnings module) : File "C: /Users/ smithab-1/Documents/duplicates_flag.py”, Line 24 df1 ['REMARKS'] = df1[‘E’] == 0 SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row indexer, col_indexer] = value instead See the caveats in the documentation: pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stabl e/user _guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: Try using df1 ['REMARKS'] = m1.values then, m1.values will be a numpy array instead of a dataframe and that should solve the warning

Comment: using `.values` is risky since this can unalign the DataFrame. better try to solve the warning upstream. But OP should edit their question with a reproducible example

Comment: Yeah, your point is fair @mozway, but it shouldn't be an issue in this case. However you are right, it is difficult to work without a reproducible example, because I created something really simple that works fine even without values, but that is not necessarily equal to OP code

Comment: let me create the example! i’ll post a new question or edit this one

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77878128/edit) this one, don't ask a new one!